# Pandas groupby calculating percentage change column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby, percentage

I'm new to pandas dataframes and I need help in understanding percentage changes.

I did generate a csv from a query in order to calculate mean values by assigning ranking to the columns.

```
rank       ds         continent           region      device     traffic
1          08/13      North america         US        mobile      7300
1          08/13      North america         US        desktop     2500
2          08/06       Europe               UK        mobile      3300
2          08/06       Europe              Italy      desktop     5600
```

And after that I did calculate  mean traffic for '1 week' and '3 week' in the second csv.

```
df_1 = df.loc[df['rank'] == '1']
df_1['traffic'] = df_1['traffic'].astype(float).fillna(0)
avg_1 = df_1.groupby(['continent','region','device']).mean()
avg_1['ds'] = '1 week'

last_3 = df.loc[df['rank'].isin(['2','3','4'])]
last_3['traffic'] = last_3['traffic'].astype(float).fillna(0)
avg_3 = last_3.groupby(['continent','region','device']).mean()
avg_3['ds'] = '3 week'
```

Final output for mean:

```
market               country       traffic       device          ds
North america         US           36015.33      mobile        1week
North america         US           40663.67      desktop       3week
Europe                UK           360270.7      mobile        1week 
Europe                Italy        1363183       desktop       3week
```

Can anyone help me to calculate the percentage change traffic as a separate column for 1week and 3 week?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got this figured out. Used pct_change()